# How to make an editor using markdowns with Qt4 and Python?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, markdown, rtf

I'd like to make a small desktop editor to take notes, that uses markdowns to format text quickly. The application should transcribe markdowns instantaneously or after clicking on a button.

For this I'd like to use Qt4 and Python.

What, in your opinion, is the most efficient way to proceed?

In the case the rich text is rendered after pressing a button, I suppose I could use QTextEdit widget for the edit-mode, but what to use to display the rich text? I want this to look good. Should I render the text in HTML? Or something else?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at how [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext) has done it. Maybe even ReText is the app you want to code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I'm looking for a solution for the same task.

Here is what I would (or hopefully will) try:

- Subclass `QTextEdit`, which can display both plain and rich text.
- supply two string properties, one containing Markdown source, the other generated HTML.
- For entering "edit mode" (however your UI will handle this)

  - `self.setText(self.markdown)`
  - `self.setReadOnly(False)`
- For leaving "edit mode":

  - `self.markdown = self.toPlainText()`
  - `self.toHtml() # convert self.markdown to self.html`
    `#               don't know yet how to achieve that`
  - `self.setHtml(self.html)`
  - `self.setReadOnly(True)`

For displaying the HTML one can use a CSS stylesheet.
As UI interface I could imagine: clicking on the readonly *display* mode switches to edit mode, [Ctrl]-[Enter] triggers HTML generation.